# HTML - Cant set <TD> Height properly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-table

In my table, I would like to keep all rows' height even and so I am setting td height with the following jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".striped tr").css("min-width", "540px").css("padding-left", "5px");
            $(".striped tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EDEDED");
            $(".striped").css("font-size", "13px");
            $(".striped td").css("min-height", "26px").css("vertical-align", "middle").css("display", "block");            
        });
```

Page looked like this before the script is applied:
[image]

after script is applied:
[image]

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Your jQuery is only calling `.css()`. Have you considered using... CSS?

Comment: You can set multiple properties at once by passing an object to `.css()`.

Comment: If it's `<tr class=striped>`, then it should be `$("tr.striped")` instead of `$(".striped tr")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `css("display", "block")`

It's causing the `td` elements to be block level and to be bumped under each other.

Answer (score 1):

Table cells have `display: table-cell`.

Setting `display: block` causes them to be treated as normal elements, not table cells.

Comment: Thanks for the quick rep. Removing the display attribute or changing display attribute's value to table-cell, both worked same. Which is better of both?